# Insert values into SQL Server using asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net

Form button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="GO" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
End Sub
```

1. What is a simple code to insert a value (generated id) into SQL Server database? When `Button1_Click` is triggered, generated id should be inserted to `tbl_batch`.
2. Should I add anything to `web.config` (like db connection)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS; Database=databasename; User Id=sa; Password=yourpassword;")
            Using cmd As SqlCommand = con.CreateCommand()
                Using da As New SqlDataAdapter
                    con.Open()

                    cmd.CommandText = "insert into ..."
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd
                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                    da.Fill(dt)

                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do CRUD operation in web.config file but I have one simple solution for you using SqlDataSource. Follow up below steps and make your stuff happen, just in simple way.

**Connection String In my Web.config:**

```
<add name="Conn" connectionString="Server=David-PC;Database=DNN711;uid=sa;pwd=sa123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

**ASPX Markup:**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="GO" onclick="Button1_Click" />

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsInsert" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Conn %>" 
        InsertCommand="Insert into tbl_batch (GeneratedID) values (@GeneratedID)"
        InsertCommandType="Text"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Button Click Event:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sdsInsert.InsertParameters.Add("GeneratedID", "123");
    sdsInsert.Insert();
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.